How to get the definition of the content model of a specific type with Contentful CLI
Contentful CLI supports exporting all content models with the following command:
$ contentful space export --skip-roles --skip-content

Let's say that we are only interested in exporting a single content model entry, as this would allow users to compare the state of a specific content model across multiple spaces.  Does Contentful CLI provide a way to export only the definition of a specific content model?
